# SSRS: Multi Columns Output from single captured column data

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, reporting-services, pivot

Captured input in SQL:

[image]

Output Suppose to be like below:

[image]

Comment: Please guide us best way of code

Comment: Without sample data (as text or better still a script to generate it) to work with or expected results that match the sample data then I can only guess. You'll probably need to use a matrix in SSSRS with a column group grouped by parameter id and a row group grouped by both Date and Hour. The data expression in the cell with have to be something like  `=FIRST(Fields!entered_value.Value)`